# How do I submit data from input="date" form to JS function?

Tags: javascript

So every time i submit a date with the button, the results are "The difference is NaN days".
Can't find the problem

```
<form method="post" action="...">
    <label for="theday">Choose your date:</label>
    <input type="date" id="theday" name="theday"/> //date input should submit the chosen date
    <button type="submit" onclick="counting()">Let's see!</button> //submit button
</form>
//this messy scripts walks in
<script type = "text/javascript">
  function counting() {
  var form = document.getElementById('theday').submit;
  var today = new Date();
  var end = new Date("theday");
  var diff= Math.abs(end-today);
  var daydiff= Math.ceil(diff/ (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); 
  document.write("The difference is " + daydiff + " days");
}
</script>
```

Comment: What's  `"kiedy"`? Because I'm pretty sure to know what it's not: a valid Date.

Comment: Did an oopsie while translating, i fixed that but nothing changed

Comment: Well, "theday" is not a valid Date either. If you mean to use the value of the form element called "theday", you need to select the element from the DOM and extract its value, and use THAT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to read the value from any element within the DOM, you need to select the element first. There is many ways to do this, but the most common and easiest for beginners is using `document.getElementById()`, which allows you to select an element from the DOM by its id attribute.

To select your date input, this would be `document.getElementById('theday')`.

Next, input elements have a property called `value` tzhat contains their current value. So in order to get the value from your date input, the code would look like this:
`document.getElementById('theday').value`

There is no reason to submit the form (this would trigger a "submit" event on the form and, depending on the "action"-attribute of the form, possibly also other things). You can always read the current values of form elements with JS, submitted or not.

Your `counting()`-function could look like this:

```
function counting() {
    var dateInput = document.getElementById('theday');
    var today = new Date();
    var end = new Date(dateInput.value);
    var diff = Math.abs(end-today);
    var daydiff = Math.ceil(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    document.write("The difference is " + daydiff + " days");
}
```

Please keep in mind that i blindly copied ythe rest of your code, assuming you do know what you're doing there. There might be better ways of doing the actual calculations, and there might be better ways besides `document.write` (which will clear the page), and so on - but this is outside the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

The issues is with this line...

```
var end = new Date("theday");
```

Inputting a string of `"theday"` into the new Date() function is invalid.

Instead, try getting the value from theday input as a properly formatted date representation and using that.